# how to extend existing LSP language server to derivative language?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

VS Code has great Bash language support -- syntax highlighting (via [shellscript](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/shellscript)), LSP support (via [Bash-IDE](https://github.com/bash-lsp/bash-language-server)), linting (via [vscode-shellcheck](https://github.com/vscode-shellcheck/vscode-shellcheck)), and a debugger (via [bash debug](https://github.com/rogalmic/vscode-bash-debug)). There is a Bash-based TAP-compliant unit test framework called [BATS](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core) that also has syntax highlighting support for some new BATS-specific keywords (via [bats](https://github.com/jetmartin/bats)). I'd primarily like to marry the Bash LSP with the BATS syntax language so that I can get individual tests listed in the VS Code outline panel, but I'd also be potentially interested in `shellcheck` linting as well (though that is a bigger project, I think).

There are pieces of all of this architecture that are extensively documented, but I haven't found anything that documents how all of these work together, let alone how to then derive off of them. A fundamental question therefor is: can I define a new language as an extension of an existing one such that I pick up all of this language support for free, albeit with different/added keyword definitions? I guess each piece has their own definition of the different syntax elements (e.g. how a "function" is defined), so perhaps I need to override each one of them individually somehow?